# emptying the input after submiting a form

Tags: reactjs, input, state

I'm trying to empty the input tag once I'm updating my state:

```js
state = {
    formName: '',
    inputs: [],
    tempInput: {
      inputLabel: '',
      inputType: '',
      inputValue: ''
    }
  };
```

this is my form:

```js
  <div className="formG">
        <form className="form-maker" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          Label:
          <input name="inputLabel" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          Type:
          <input name="inputType" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          Value
          <input name="inputValue" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          Form Name
          <input name="formName" type="text" onChange={this.formName} />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
```

that's how I handle the change

```js
 handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState(currentState => ({
      tempInput: { ...currentState.tempInput, [name]: value }
    }));
  };
```

and I tried to just empty the tempInput but it doesn't work, anybody knows why?

```js
 handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const inputs = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.tempInput];
    const { tempInput } = this.state;
    tempInput.inputLabel = '';
    tempInput.inputType = '';
    tempInput.inputValue = '';
    this.setState({ inputs, tempInput });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is an **uncontrolled** component, so they are not controlled by the state fields. That's why your approach didn't work. Instead you can do `e.target.reset()` which will clear the entire form. But if you want to reset some input, you can access them and set the `.value` to `""` as I had shown below.

> An uncontrolled component works like form elements do outside of React. When a user inputs data into a form field (an input box, dropdown, etc) the updated information is reflected without React needing to do anything. However, this also means that you can’t force the field to have a certain value. From [Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)

So your `handleSubmit` method will look like:

```
handleSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const inputs = [...this.state.inputs, this.state.tempInput];
  // ....
  // The below will reset entire form.
  // e.target.reset();
  // If you want some of them to empty.
  const { elements } = e.target
  elements['inputLabel'].value = "";
  elements['inputType'].value = "";
  elements['inputValue'].value = "";
};
```

Check the doc of [`HTMLFormElement.elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm unfamiliar with e.target.reset(), where do I add it in the code?

Comment: @AlexAlex check now

Comment: oh thank you it works, but it empties my form name input as well, I just want to empty the inputlabel,input value and type, is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @AlexAlex Yes give me few sec

Comment: @AlexAlex check again

Comment: Overall this will get you a working solution but you do not benefit from reacts state tracking I would not use this solution.

Comment: i down voted you on accident my appologies i removed it.

Comment: @joshuafermin thanks for saying. Uncontrolled components I used many times in my projects, and used dumb components.. It makes sense when you know where it fits well. Adding state to components always is not a good idea either.

Comment: yes I agree but for any form components I always lean towards statefull components to manage the data. But knowing both sides pros and cons of an uncontrolled component vs a controlled component is just as important.

Comment: @joshuafermin I agree now with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your input tags are not displaying the value of your state.
1) pull the individual values out of tempInput
2) use the value stored in your state that is then updated by your handleChange.
3) In your handleSubmit function reset your individual values to and empty string.

your handleChange should look like:

```
handleChange = e => {
     const { name, value } = e.target;
     this.setState([name]: value);
};
```

your jsx should look like :

```
<form className="form-maker" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
      Label:
      <input name="inputLabel" value={this.state.inputLabel} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      Type:
      <input name="inputType" value={this.state.inputType}  type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      Value
      <input name="inputValue" value={this.state.inputType} type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      Form Name
      <input name="formName" value={this.state.formName} type="text" onChange={this.formName} />
      <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, now I  understand that I was missing the value that updates the state in my input !

Comment: @AlexAlex This answer shows how to make a controlled component. Please know this difference for your future code. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're mutating the original state. You can copy and then only set the state. Just changing the following will work fine for you.

Replace this:

```
const { tempInput } = this.state;
```

With this:

```
const { tempInput } = {...this.state}; // copy the state
```

Also, be sure to bind the state value in your input elements like this to make them controlled component:

```
<input name="inputLabel" type="text" 
  onChange={this.handleChange} 
  value={this.state.tempInput.inputLabel || ''} />
```

And your handler should be:

```
handleChange = e => {
     const { value } = e.target;
     this.setState({value}); 
// now, value will correspond to the controlled component
};
```

---

Also take care react suggest to use [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) as far as possible:

> In most cases, we recommend using controlled components to implement forms.

Comment: the OP has **uncontrolled** component. Changing state will not do anything in the form values, as they are having their own state in memory.

Comment: was updating while you commented.